# Help understanding the working of the Maxwell-Boltzmann Probability Distribution Curve

Tags: probability, statistics, probability-distributions

I was reading about the Kinetic Theory of gases (in Resnick and Halliday) in which I came across The Maxwell-Boltzmann Probability Distribution function for velocities of gases which is defined as:

$$ P(v) = 4\pi (\frac{M}{2\pi RT})^{3/2}v^{2}\exp(-Mv^{2}/2RT)$$

It is said that the probability of a the velocity of a gas lying between the speeds $v_1, v_2$ is given by the improper integral:

$$ \int_{v_1}^{v_2} P(v) dv $$

It is also mentioned that since all the speeds of the gases lie between $0$ and $\infty$, the integral: $$ \int_0^{\infty} P(v) dv = 1$$

I am kinda able to understand the intuition behind these statements but I would like to know why is it that integral from $v_1$ to $v_2$ of the product of $P(v)$ and $dv$ gives us the probability of finding a gas molecule having a velocity between $v_1$ and $v_2$?

Also, it is given that for calculating the average velocity ($v_{avg}$) , it is computed by the integral : $$ \int_0^{\infty} v \ \ P(v) dv $$

Can someone please shed some light on why we are multiplying $P(v)dv$ with $v$ ? Also since we are calculating average velocity, how come we aren't dividing by the number of gas molecules in the container?

I am completely new to how probability distribution curves work, so feel free to assume that I have no prior knowledge on this topic and a detailed, intuitive explanation would be preferred :)

Comment: Since you said you are completely new to these kinds of calculations, I recommend you to have a read on "Probability Density Function" https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Probability_density_function first. $p(v)$ is a pdf, and $p(v)dv$ gives a infinitesimal probability of the velocity in the infinitesimal interval $(v, v+dv)$, so you sum them up / integrate from $v_1$ to $v_2$ to obtain the desired probability. For the expectation question, you may also have some reading first, or you may also analog to the discrete counterpart: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Weighted_arithmetic_mean

Comment: @BGM thanks for the links , I have looked into them. Will do more reading , although I did have a doubt. When we are calculating the average velocity , why do we need to take the velocity as a weight by multiplying it into the probability ? Why can’t we just sum up the probabilities and divide by number of molecules ? What quantity will that give us ?

Comment: Say you observe the velocities of $6$ molecules to be $1, 1, 1, 2, 2, 3$. The sample average is obtained by summing them and divided by $6$: $\displaystyle \frac {1+1+1+2+2+3} {6} = \frac {1\times3+2\times2+3\times1} {6} = 1 \times \frac {3} {6} + 2 \times \frac {2} {6} + 3 \times \frac {1} {6}$ The latter expression somehow show you the weighted mean concept. If you have a discrete random variable $X$ with $\Pr\{X=1\} = \frac {3} {6}, \Pr\{X=2\} = \frac {2} {6}, \Pr\{X=3\} = \frac {1} {6}$ then the expectation will equal to the above formula as well. Hopefully this give you some intuition.

Comment: @BGM Oh my gosh thank you so much! Instead of taking the weighted sum with frequency of a particularl speed of a molecule , we just take its probability which is basically the frequency / the number of occurrences of that speed. It makes sense now ! Although I still don’t get why we don’t divide that entire integral by the number of molecules , so where is the $\frac{1}{N}$ term? Or can we say that it is included in the probability density function itself ? Like in your example , Probablity of $ X \{1\} = \frac{3}{6} $ which already has our 1/N term.